# How can i switch focus of JTextAreas and write on currently focused?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have a problem with my program:
I have a 2 JTextAreas, and i want to switch between them and write on them using my JButtons.My code looks like this:

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent v) {
    Object source=v.getSource();
    if(source==button0){
        dane0.append("0");
    }
    if(source==button1){
        dane0.append("1");
    }
            ..............
   }
```

My two JTextAreas are dane0 and dane1, i want to switch between them and write on them. How can i switch focus( using a another button ) and change my code, to write on them ? ( Now I can only write on dane0 ). It's the project of simple calculator with gui, so i have buttons with numbers and symbols like "+","-","*" etc.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a 2 JTextAreas

Why do you have two text areas? Usually a Calculator only has one display field.

> i want to switch between them and write on them.

So then you need a button (like "Switch Text Area") or something that tells the program to switch. So you would need to create an instance variable like "currentTextArea". Then every time you click the "Switch Text Area" button you toggle the currentTextArea to be either dane0 or dane1. Then you need to change you actionPerformed code to reference the "currentTextArea" variable.

I must say you design really doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Because it's binary calculator, and i want to see both numbers in the same time. I used JRadioButton to resolve that problem.

Comment: @user3407967, `Because it's binary calculator, and i want to see both numbers in the same time` - so then every time you add a number you need to update both text areas.